# Edit TableAdapter CommandText getting Null ReferenceException

Tags: c#, sql, .net, dataset, tableadapter

Hello I'm trying to edit my `klientTableAdapter.CommanText` which is `TableAdapter` in dynamically created `DataSet` called `DSSchema` - this was dynamically created when creating report using `ReportViewer`.

```
string sqlcomEvent = "SELECT akce,name,surname,rodcis,(Cast([street] as nvarchar(MAX)) + ', '+ city + ', ' + ZIP) AS Adresa, odjezd, sitting, rocnik FROM dbo.klient WHERE (event=@event";

for (int a = 0; a < CommonEvents.Count(); a++)
{
    sqlcomEvent += " OR event='" + CommonEvents[a]+"'";
}
sqlcomEvent += " )AND year=@year ORDER BY SITTING";
// TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'dtourDataSet.klient' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
this.klientTableAdapter.Adapter.SelectCommand.CommandText = sqlcomEvent ;            
this.klientTableAdapter.Fill(this.dtourDataSet.klient,zajezd,klientClass.Rocnik());
this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
```

I believe the `NullReferenceException` is raised because I havent declared klientTableAdapter before, but when I add this line `var klientTableAdapter = new klientTableAdapter();` I get error:

`tours.TiskSchemaDoprava.klientTableAdapter is a field; but is used like a type`

Would anyone please help me solve this out ?

This works perfectly for me but Iam not sure if there isn't smarter way to do so?

```
this.klientTableAdapter.Fill(this.dtourDataSet.klient,zajezd,klientClass.Rocnik());
this.klientTableAdapter.Adapter.SelectCommand.CommandText = sqlcomZaj;
this.klientTableAdapter.Fill(this.dtourDataSet.klient, zajezd, klientClass.Rocnik());
this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a field:

```
this.klientTableAdapter
```

It's type has the same name as the field name. So when you say `new klientTableAdapter()` it doesn't know whether you are referring to the type of to the field, and as the field is defined in the class it is picking the field: and you can't 'new' a field. The easiest thing to do is to rename the field, and let Visual Studio take care of renaming it wherever it's used. Or do that to the type and give a standard name with a capital at the front `KlientTableAdapter` so the compiler can disambiguate the field from its type.